# DDMS file explorer doesn't show any files and folders of my motorola defy after reinstalling JDK, why?

Tags: android, adt, ddms, eclipse-indigo

I've reinstalled my JDK 6(x64).
After that allmost everything looked as before, but the file explorer view doesn't show my files anymore.

That's like it's looking like now
[image]

Some system information:

The emulator's files are still displayed.
There is no LogCat-Error and the Android Console doesn't show anything either.
My Desktop OS is Windows7.

Can anyone explain me, why it doesn't work and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the phone's fault after reflashing a new SBF, it worked.
By rooting the phone something went wrong on my defy.